# Issue using JAXB, my POJO's fields are not being Mapped

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, maven, jaxb

I am using Java 8 Springboot with Maven.

When I try to unmarshall the XML and map the FTMessage object with the given parameters, the object is created, but all the fields of the object are mapped
to null.
When wrapping the unmarshaller in a try-catch, JAXB runs and no errors are thrown.

So the resulting is:

`userShortName = null` and `filename = null`

Here is my code:

```java
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( FTMessage.class );
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlMessage); //xmlMessage is a string.
            FTMessage msg = ((FTMessage) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader)); //msg ends up with fields populated with null.
```

And my Object Class:

```java
    package com.project.message;
    
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "FTMessage", namespace = "https://www.example.com/exmpl" )
    public class FTMessage /*implements Serializable*/ {
        
        @XmlElement(name = "UserShortName")
        private String userShortName;
        
        @XmlElement(name = "Filename")
        private String filename;
    
    public FTMessage () {
    }
    
    public FTMessage (String userShortName, String filename) {
        this.userShortName= userShortName;
        this.fundShortName = filename;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FTMessage {userShortName: " + this.userShortName+ ", " +
                       "filename : " + this.filename + "}";
    }
        
        public String getUserShortName() {
            return userShortName;
        }
        
        public void setUserShortName(String userShortName) {
            this.userShortName = userShortName;
        }
        
        public String getFilename() {
            return filename;
        }
        
        public void setFilename(String filename) {
            this.filename = filename;
        }
    }
```

as well as my XML String:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FTMessage xmlns="https://www.example.com/exmpl"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <UserShortName>Jerome</UserShortName>
    <Filename>NotReal.csv</Filename>
</FTMessage>
```

If I marshal it I get a file with the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:FTMessage xmlns:ns2="https://www.example.com/exmpl">
<UserShortName>Jerome</UserShortName>
<Filename>notReal</Filename>
</ns2:FTMessage>
```

Answer (score 0):

The salution which I found was adding the namespace attribute-not only to the `@XmlRootElement` but also to all the `@XmlElement`'s like so:

```
@XmlElement(name = "UserShortName", namespace = "https://www.example.com/exmpl")
```